# Chrome Dev Tools horizontal split

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome's Dev Tools used to show HTML and CSS windows split horizontally. Now they're split vertically. How can I get it back to horizontal split?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As of Chrome 87:

**Settings --> Preferences --> Panel Layout**

There you can choose horizontal or vertical split.

Comment: Note the settings here is a gear icon on chrometools window itself, not your chrome browser settings per-se

Answer (score 3):

In the top right corner of dev tools, you will find windows icons (left to X).Press & hold it,you will get the option to horizontal split it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: When I click it the options are: Dock side, Show console,Search all files, More tools, Shortcuts, Settings, Help.
Where's the option to horizontally split?

Comment: Oh, found it. Settings > General > Appearance > Panel layout.

Comment: No. I added a screenshot to the question post so you can see.

Comment: The highlighted button is the shortcut to achieve it (new image)

Comment: No, that just docks it to the bottom.

Comment: This answer is outdated.  See below.